# Using wbimport on sql workbench/j with presto driver

Tags: sql, import, presto, sql-workbench-j

so I am using workbench to import a 160k line text file into a table code is:

```
Wbimport
-usepgcopy
-type=text
-endrow=164841
-file=‘book1.csv’
-table=it.table1
-delimiter=,
-multiline=true
```

So I have tried this with a 3 line version of my 160k line file and it completed in a few seconds. This only seems to complete in auto commit mode, and when I try to run it on the full 160k line file it takes over 200h to complete any idea why - or alternatives.

I am using workbench build 125 and presto jdbc-0.216

Thanks

Comment: Presto JDBC does not support batch `INSERT` yet (see https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/1777). Also, what connector do you insert to? If you eg use Presto with PostgreSQL, you can load data directly to PostgreSQL, which has some dedicated tools for this.

Comment: You can, however, skip INSERT at all. If you have eg Presto configured with S3 (or HDFS), you just put the CSV file somewhere and "map" it in Presto Hive connector as an external table.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the reason is that the overall transaction gets to large and this imposes too big a load on wbimport and the jdbc connection. It would probably work much faster if you break this up into separation imports of e.g. 1000 records per import.

If you cut up the file first into multiple files and then import them one at a time, you are also avoiding the repeated read of the large file to find the right record.

Comment: You can use `-commitEvery=1000` with WbImport, no need to split up the file